# Python - y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape instead

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Let's consider data :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,80)
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
y = np.sin(x)+np.random.normal(0,0.4,80)  
y[y<1/2] = 0  
y[y>1/2] = 1
clf=LogisticRegression(solver="saga", max_iter = 1000)
```

I want to fit logistic regression where y is dependent variable, and x is independent variable. But while I'm using :

```
clf.fit(x,y)
```

I see error

```
'y  should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (80, 80) instead'.
```

I tried to reshape data by using

```
y=y.reshape(-1,1)
```

But I end up with array of length 6400! (How come?)

Could you please give me a hand with performing this regression ?

Comment: 80 times 80 is 6400

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the order of your operations:

First geneate *x* and *y* as **1-D** arrays:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 8)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.4, 8)
```

Then (after *y* was generated) reshape *x*:

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
```

## Edit following a comment as of 2022-02-20

The source of the problem in the original code is that;

- `x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,80)` - generates a 1-D array.
- `x = x.reshape(-1,1)` - reshapes it into a **2-D** array, with one column and
  as many rows as needed.
- `y = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0,0.4,80)` - operates on a columnar array and
  a 1-D array (treated here as a single row array).
- the effect is that *y* is a **2-D** array (80 * 80).
- then the attempt to reshape *y* gives a single column array with 6400 rows.

The proper solution is that both *x* and *y* should be initially **1-D**
(single row) arrays and my code does just this.
Then both arrays can be reshaped.

Comment: If @Valdi_Bo could kindly explain the logic behind it.  It is not clear (a) how the order of operation could fix this problem, and (b) how reshaping x removes the error when the error is about y.  The solution provided in this case but not in my case.  Hence, providing some further explanation would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @seakyourpeak: The order matters because numpy [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) arrays when the dims are mismatched. When x was reshaped to (80, 1), the sin(x) portion of y has the dim (80, 1). The normal portion is (80, ). When adding these arrays, numpy broadcast dims to (80, 80). If the reshape is called after the expression of y, y dim is (80, ).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error and solving it via reshape but it didn't work

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
```

Actually, this was happening due to the wrong placement of [] brackets around np.argmax, below is the wrong code and correct one, notice the positioning of [] around the np.argmax in both the snippets

Wrong Code

```
ax[i,j].set_title("Predicted Watch : "+str(le.inverse_transform([pred_digits[prop_class[count]]])) +"\n"+"Actual Watch : "+str(le.inverse_transform(np.argmax([y_test[prop_class[count]]])).reshape(-1,1)))
```

Correct Code

```
ax[i,j].set_title("Predicted Watch :"+str(le.inverse_transform([pred_digits[prop_class[count]]]))+"\n"+"Actual Watch : "+str(le.inverse_transform([np.argmax(y_test[prop_class[count]])])))
```

Answer (score 0):

'y  should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (80, 80) instead'.

this error solution below

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=2)

train_test_split method kind of above kept in a right way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).